# Working SQL produces type and syntax errors with Node and pg-promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, pg-promise

I'm working with Node and Express, and using the pg-promise library to interact with my Postgres database. I have many queries set up and they all work fine. I have written a query no different than the rest that works when tested out in the Postgres command line. All it does is get a list of filenames from each entry in the "awards" table belonging to a particular user. However, when my server tries to execute the code, it throws multiple exceptions:

> TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
>
> syntax error at or near \"JOIN\"

The relevant code is:

```
const GET_ALL_PDFS = PS('getAllPDFs', `SELECT pdf_filename AS filenames
                                   FROM awards
                                   JOIN users ON users.id = awards.award_giver
                                   WHERE users.id = $1;`);

UserManagementDAO.getAllPDFs = (userId, cb) => {
db.any(GET_ALL_PDFS, userId)
    .then(result => {
        cb(null, result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        winston.error(`Error fetching all PDF filenames for user ${userId}: ${err}`);
        cb(err);
    });
};
```

I've tried using '' instead of ``, putting the SQL statement on one line, rewriting the entire SQL statement, using db.manyOrNone instead of db.any, putting the SQL statement in directly instead of using a prepared statement, explicitly using INNER JOIN instead of JOIN, and so far nothing has worked. I always get the same errors.

Comment: That specific error tells you that it doesn't like the multi-line breaks you are using. Putting that query into a single string should resolve the issue.

Comment: Making the query a single string does not fix the issue or change the error message.

Comment: This error is clearly outside of `pg-promise`. There is something wrong with your query, just not obvious from what you provided here. At this point I can only suggest that you post the entire error that's reported, and not just the message part, so that at least it shows where the error is coming from.

Comment: The entire errors are:

{"message":"Error fetching all PDF filenames for user 2: TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer","level":"error"}

{"message":"Error removing PDF award entries for user 2: error: syntax error at or near \"JOIN\"","level":"error"}

Comment: That doesn't seem enough context information to understand the error. It is definitely not from `pg-promise`, so must be from somewhere else.